# Is it correct to add booleans in order to count the number of true values in a vector?

Tags: design

Is it conceptually correct to sum a vector of booleans? From a mathematical point of view, I would argue it's not: `True + True != 2`. But it's quite practical to do so still! Example using the vectorised `Python` library `numpy`:

```
In [1]: X = rand(10)

In [2]: large = X>0.6

In [3]: large.dtype
Out[3]: dtype('bool')

In [4]: large.sum()
Out[4]: 7
```

I don't like it, but it's very practical. Is this a good practice?

**Update**: the aim is to count the number of true values in a vector.\

**Update 2013-02-18**: I just discovered the numpy function [`count_nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html#numpy.count_nonzero) does *exactly* what I need in a proper way. That means that as far as `Python` is concerned, there is no need to use the "dirty" way.

Comment: In some languages "true" is -1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say it is not semantically proper to add True and True to get two.  It may work, but it seems to rely on an implementation detail.

Python defines a few things as `False`, such as:

```
""
0
0.00
None, 
[], 
(),
.__bool__() evaluates to False, 
etc...
```

and everything else is `True`.

The `+` operator in python, when used on a `bool` will first convert it to `int`.

```
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
>>> True + True
2
```

If you choose to do so in Python, make sure you comment your code accordingly.